# Find ideal window of values in pandas dataframe column using rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 

col_1          col_2         col_3
 1              5.6           2.1
 2              4.3           2.3
 3              6.2           2.25
 4              5.2           2.15
 5              4.7           2.11
 6              5.1           2.10
 7              4.4           2.24
 8              6.1           2.12
```

Is there a way I can use pandas `rolling` or another function/technique to find a **consecutive** set of **3** or **X** number of rows based on `col_3` where the values are stable (i.e. within a range of 0.05 from one another indicating that each of the samples (i.e. `col_1`) are showing consistency in results? Essentially specifying a window of stable values based on `col_3` to extract and save the window values in a numpy array.

I've tried to simplify if it to look for a set of **consecutive** values based on `col_1` that are between 2.10 and 2.25, but haven't been able to get it to work. Is there a way to ensure the output values are consecutive?

So in the example, I would get back the following as an output:

```
col_1          col_2         col_3
 4              5.2           2.15
 5              4.7           2.11
 6              5.1           2.10
```

which I can then concatenate the 3 values in `col_3` as an array/list?

Comment: Do all the values have to be within 0.05 of each other, or just adjacent values? e.g. does it have to be `2.15, 2.11, 2.10` or is `2.10, 2.14, 2.17` valid?

Comment: @Nick The goal is to have all of the values be within 0.05 of each other. ```pd.diff()``` can get us to difference calculations between rows. But unclear how to ensure they're consecutive and of window size = 3 or X. So only [2.15, 2.11, 2.10].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider only successive differences, you can use a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
N = 3
thresh = 0.05

# form new group when the absolute difference is > threshold
group = df['col_3'].diff().abs().gt(thresh).cumsum()

# keep only groups of size ≥ N
out = df[df.groupby(group).transform('size').ge(N)]
```

To consider the full slice, you would need to use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), which is more complex as you first need to identify if there were at least N values within the threshold, then expanding the selection window with a second `rolling`:

```
out = df[(df['col_3']
          .rolling(N).apply(lambda g: abs(g.max()-g.min())<=thresh)
          [::-1].rolling(N).max().eq(1)[::-1]
          )]
```

Output:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
3      4    5.2   2.15
4      5    4.7   2.11
5      6    5.1   2.10
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "full slice"? Also, what does "ge" mean in the line ```df[df.groupby(group).transform('size').ge(N)]```? is it supposed to be```.get(N)```? or ```get_group()```?

Comment: By full slice, I meant not only the difference between the n/n+1 values but overall in the whole set of successive values. `ge` meant greater or equal (`>=`)

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `rolling` function must be a number, so you cannot return a `list` that is the rolling result into `col_3` directly.

You should use `window.to_list()` to get the windowed value list first and then produce the result.

code:

```
import pandas as pd

def check_stable(args, thr=0.05, length=3):
    if len(args) != length:
        return None
    if max(args) - min(args) > thr:
        return None
    return args

windowed = [window.to_list() for window in df["col_3"].rolling(3)]
df["result"] = pd.Series(windowed).apply(check_stable, length=3)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing help on getting the windowed value list. I'm trying to get my final output to be how I stated above in the question with only rows 4, 5, and 6 left.